# will netbeans or eclipse install mysql for me as a plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

will netbeans or eclipse install mysql for me as a plugin? (preferrably netbeans)

(on a windows machine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, MySQL is not a plugin. It's a fully independent relational database server. You can just install it separately and integrate it in your IDE. Both Eclipse and Netbeans supports integration of external databases using a JDBC driver so that you can access it from within the IDE.

But, by coincidence, Netbeans has a [bundled download with MySQL and Glassfish](http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/6.1/mysql_bundle/) available (which is although somewhat outdated). Note that it is not necessary to download it if you already have Netbeans and/or don't need Glassfish. Just download MySQL separately from [their own homepage](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

i never felt that mysql-plugin for IDE was necessary (am using IntelliJ). the sql syntax is already quite universal, so in my view big tools aren't necessary in many cases (compared to other programming setup, e.g. Java-development).

i always use directly mysql CLI client. it gives you the power of the command line and also auto-completion.